# SublimeText3 Fold/Unfold all methods

Tags: sublimetext3

I am using SublimeText3 for C++ and Java. I am wondering if there is a way to fold all of the methods in a file / class, and then unfold them all, regardless of where the caret is. Or is there a way to list all the functions / methods.

Basically I would like to be able to enter a file and see all the methods at one quick glance.

Thanks

Comment: Does the built-in `Goto` menu -> `Goto Symbol...` meet your requirements? It will list all functions and methods, and you can filter it by name if you are searching for something

Comment: Or `Edit` menu -> `Code Folding` -> `Fold All`

Comment: You can use fold by level 2 and unfold All. You can also set a new keybinding to those commands.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Using the Sublime Text 3 menu, you can find `EDIT` -> `Code Folding` -> which exposes the folding methods and will helpfully tell you the default keyboard shortcuts they are assigned to.

By default you press `Ctrl+K`, then `Ctrl+1` to fold all subroutines. Then, to unfold all I would press `Ctrl+K` then `Ctrl+J`.

If this does not work for your file type / syntax, try `Ctrl+K, Ctrl+2` and above to see if another folding level works for you.

Unfortunately for me, the proprietary code I work with required custom syntax and a custom function written in our in-house package to fold all of our functions (a new sublime command written in python and installed as a package).

Comment: The Level 2 fold shortcut - Ctrl+K, Ctrl+2, works perfectly to fold all methods/functions in my Java code, in case anyone stumbles upon this post. Thanks Chris

Answer (score 38):

**More simple**

Select the *code* and *press*:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> to *fold*

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> to *unfold*

---

**Updates**

You can also select an element. Exemple:

[image]

Comment: No need to select code, `Ctrl + Shift + [` to fold and `Ctrl + Shift + ]` to unfold works in Sublime3, need to put cursor on the line which you want to fold.

Comment: @S.Yadav I tested on version 3.2.1 Build 3207.
Really I can select an element and use as said. At the time I don't remember testing whether it worked or not, or if it was a release change. I made a complement in the answer. Thank you ✌️

Answer (score 9):

Open the console (**`View -> Console`** or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>) with a source code file focused and enter the following commands at the bottom:

```
view.run_command("fold_all")
view.run_command("unfold_all")
```

to see their effect.

These commands can be bound with [custom key bindings](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/customization/key_bindings.html) or put into the [Command Palette](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/command_palette.html) for easy use.

Answer (score 4):

Mac: Go to **Edit/Code Folding** as image bellow:

[Details image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqa5R.jpg)