# What is the feature that lets you "minimize" text in an IDE like VS Code called?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, formatting

I've simply been wondering what to call it. Also, does anyone know any extensions for VS Code that would let make custom ones, not simply the automade ones.

[While true and dropdown arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKvzL.png)

I've kept searching the web, but haven't found anything. I have also found no leads as to what it might be.

Comment: It's code folding.

Comment: Second part: https://burkeholland.gitbook.io/vs-code-can-do-that/exercise-3-navigation-and-refactoring/folding-sections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some editors, it's called Code Folding.

- [VS Code user docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_folding).
- [JetBrains user docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-source-code.html#code_folding) ([and more user docs (about settings)](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-folding-settings.html)).
- [Eclipse user docs](https://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/using_code_folding.htm).
- [Spyder user docs](https://www.spiderbasic.com/documentation/reference/ide_editing.html#:%7E:text=By%20clicking%20on%20the%20%5B%2D%5D,overview%20of%20larger%20source%20files.).
- [related question for Sublime Text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34958855/11107541).
- [Notepad++ user docs](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/views/#folding).
- [Vim wiki page](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Folding).
- [Emacs wiki page](https://wikemacs.org/wiki/Folding).

In some, it's called "collapsing" and "expanding" regions / "outlining".

- [Visual Studio user docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/outlining).
- [Xcode forum thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/109889).
- [TextMate user docs](https://macromates.com/manual/en/navigation_overview#collapsing_text_blocks_foldings).

Answer (score -1):

This is [code folding](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_folding), and in python they can be controlled by `#region` and  `#endregion`.

[image]